# Creating a div using jquery with style tag

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I am trying to create a div element using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ss = {
        id: "foo",
        class: "attack",
        dataa: "hhh",
        style:{
            "color":"red"
        }
    }
    var $div = $("<div>", ss);
    $div.html("dfg");
    $("body").append($div);
```

It creates the element, but the style object is not adding properly.

Is there a workaround to add style within the tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `css` not `style`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ss = {
    id: "foo",
    class: "attack",
    dataa: "hhh",
    css: {
      "color": "red"
    }
  };
  var $div = $("<div>", ss);
  $div.html("dfg");
  $("body").append($div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or you can use `style` but it should be string as we are setting in style attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ss = {
    id: "foo",
    class: "attack",
    dataa: "hhh",
    style: 'color: red'
  };
  var $div = $("<div>", ss);
  $div.html("dfg");
  $("body").append($div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

use below code . instead of `style` use `css`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hs3zhnms/)

```
var ss = {
    id: "foo",
    class: "attack",
    dataa: "hhh",
    css:{
        "color":"red"
    }
}
```